# Changing data dynamically using Ajax in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, json, codeigniter

I have this like button, when I click this one, the no of likes will change automatically. The number of likes is displayed above the button. To do this, I've used ajax to implement this function.

This is my code in the View:

```
<p id='state'>
   <i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> <?php echo $countLike;?> likes &bull; 
   <i class='fa fa-thumbs-down'></i> <?php echo $countDisLike;?> dislikes</p>

   <button class='detailButton' name='like_name' id='click_like' value='<?php echo $link;?>' title='Like this post'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> Like</button>
```

Javascript code above the view:

```
<script type="javascript/text">
$(document).ready(function){
  $("#click_like").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = document.getElementById("click_name").value;
    jQuery.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/photoCheese/like_total/",
      dataType:'json',
      data: {like_id = id},
      success: function(res){
        if(res){
          jQuery("div#state").html(res.no_likes);
        }      
      }
    });
  });
});
```

My controller:

```
public function like_total(){
        $id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
        $upload = $_GET['like_id'];
        $data = array('like' => 1,
                        'userID'=>$id,
                        'uploadID'=>$_GET['like_id']);

        $this->photoCheese_model->get_like_total($data,$upload);

        return json_encode($data);
    }
```

Model:

```
public function get_like_total($data,$uplaod){
        $success = $this->db->insert('tbl_like',$data);

        if($success){
            $this->db->select('uploadID,SUM(`like`) as no_likes',false);
            $this->db->where('uploadID',$upload);
            $this->db->where('like !=',2);

            $query = $this->db->get();


        }
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

When I try to run this code, it has no effect. I mean, it shows no result at all. I'm new to ajax and it is my first time also to implement this one. Please, help me with this one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

this is wrong in your code.Also take reference from [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
data: {like_id = id},
```

it would be

```
data: {like_id:id},
```

Answer (score 1):

change data like below use `:` in place of `=`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

jQuery.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/photoCheese/like_total/",
      dataType:'json',
      data: {like_id : id},
      success: function(res){

          $("#like").html(res);

      }
    });
```

and your `HTML` for showing like count like below

```
<p id='state'>
   <i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> <b id="like"><?php echo $countLike;?></b> likes &bull; 
   <i class='fa fa-thumbs-down'></i> <?php echo $countDisLike;?> dislikes</p>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77193/discussion-on-answer-by-vicky-changing-data-dynamically-using-ajax-in-codeignite).

Answer (score 1):

As stated by saty your data object is not correct.

In addition, and more important, this line fails:

```
jQuery("div#state").html(res.no_likes);
```

Your `#state` is a `p` element not a `div` so the selector should not select anything at all. Thus resulting in not seeing any change. The next error in that line is that it replaces the complete HTML with the number, instead of just updating the number. Try this HTML and JS instead:

html:

```
<p id='state'>
    <i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i><span id="state_likes"><?php echo $countLike;?></span> likes &bull; 
    <i class='fa fa-thumbs-down'></i> <?php echo $countDisLike;?> dislikes
</p>

<button class='detailButton' name='like_name' id='click_like' value='<?php echo $link;?>' title='Like this post'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> Like</button>
```

javascript:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/photoCheese/like_total/",
  dataType:'json',
  data: {like_id: id},
  success: function(res){
    if(res){
      jQuery("#state_likes").html(res.no_likes);
    }      
  }
});
```

That should get you in the right direction. If you want I can refactor your code some more for readability.

Comment: I've edited my code already but still no result at all

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your code

```
data: {like_id = id},
```

into

```
data: {like_id : id},
```

or you can also pass it like as

```
data: "like_id ="+id,
```

**SideNotes**

1) Within your Controller. Why you were using `$_GET['like_id']`
 you can use CI function as

```
$upload = $this->input->get('like_id');
```

2) Within your controller it seems you were returning encoded `$data` and not the `result`

```
return json_encode($data);
```

it should be

```
$result = $this->photoCheese_model->get_like_total($data,$upload);

return json_encode($result);
```

You can check your consoles using console.log() as

```
success: function(res){
        console.log(res);
        if(res){
          jQuery("div#state").html(res.no_likes);
        }      
      }
```

Comment: What variable should I returned?

Comment: I've updated already my code

Comment: @Jen143Me. Place `console.log(res)` within your success function and check your console what you got over there

Comment: Is my JavaScript code stays the same? Do I need to change anything to the view? cuz still no result.

Comment: How should I see the result after putting the console and running the code?

Comment: Check my updated answer. @Jen143Me and after refreshing your webpage press `F12` key and there you'll find console check what you were getting over there

Comment: There are many errors on the console tab

Comment: `GET http://localhost:81/PhotoCheese/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.map 404 (Not Found) `

Comment: Are you getting any `json` within console

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: There is no json within my console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77167/discussion-between-uchiha-and-jen143me).

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code by opening Inspect element in Chrome and then press 'like_name' button and see the if there is new link added to Network Tab if No then your your is just not calling the function, If yes there is new link the click on that and check response and header,
BTW remove the `event.preventDefault();` its only for submit button

[image]

Please upload an image similer to this one containg your result

[image]

Use this image as reference to how to upload image

Comment: there are 2 links added but the status is error

Comment: what is the response ?

Comment: equest URL:http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.map
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified

Comment: Request URL:http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.map

Comment: Status Code:304 Not Modified

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:81/PhotoCheese/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.map

Comment: Status Code:404 Not Found

Comment: how will I post the screenshot? it was saved in my desktop

Comment: edit post and click on image icon in editor and upload and save

Comment: what should I replace with the http://..

Comment: just click on image icon upload and  save changes nothing else