# Displaying the data dynamically using Ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

In this code, after clicking the like button, the data is added in the database already. What I wanted to do now is I would like after adding the data, I will query the total like of the chosen item and display it without loading the page.

This is my code for now:

My View:

```
<p id='state'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i><span id="likeThis"><?php echo $countLike;?></span> likes &bull; <i class='fa fa-thumbs-down'></i><?php echo $countDisLike;?> dislikes &bull;<i class='fa fa-thumbs-down'></i><a href='<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/photoCheese/deleteUploadPic/<?php echo $row['uploadID'];?>'>Delete Picture</a></p>
 <input type="button" onclick="getVal(this.value)" class='detailButton1' name='like_name' id='like_id' value='<?php echo $link;?>' title='Like this post'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> Like</input>
```

Javascript:

`function getVal(value)
  {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/photoCheese/like_total/",
      dataType:'json',
      data: {like_id : value},
      success: function(res){
        alert(res.no_likes);
        if(res){
          jQuery("#likeThis").html(res.no_likes);
        }

      }
    });`

Controller:

```
public function like_total(){
        $id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
        $upload = $this->input->get('like_id');
        $data = array('like' => 1,
                        'userID'=>$id,
                        'uploadID'=>$_GET['like_id']);

        $result = $this->photoCheese_model->get_like_total($data,$upload);


        return json_encode($result);
    }
```

Model:

```
public function get_like_total($data,$uplaod){
        $success = $this->db->insert('tbl_like',$data);

        if($success){
            $this->db->select('uploadID,SUM(`like`) as no_likes',false);
            $this->db->where('uploadID',$upload);
            $this->db->where('like !=',2);

            $query = $this->db->get();


        }
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

This code will not display the total_likes. What's wrong with this one?

Comment: If $config['allow_get_array'] is FALSE(default is TRUE), destroys the global GET array.

Comment: where should I put that code?

Comment: in you config.php file

Comment: It became worst..i could not add a data anymore

Comment: show where your set this parameter add your question

Comment: What is the purpose of changing the default one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77277/discussion-between-saty-and-jen143me).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing data dynamically using Ajax in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095941/changing-data-dynamically-using-ajax-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @Uchiha this is another problem I wanted to ask. It is about displaying the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the helps and research. This is the running code of this problem.

In the View:

```
<p id='state'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i><span class="likeThis"><?php echo $countLike;?></span> likes &bull; <i class='fa fa-thumbs-down'></i><?php echo $countDisLike;?> dislikes &bull;<i class='fa fa-thumbs-down'></i><a href='<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/photoCheese/deleteUploadPic/<?php echo $row['uploadID'];?>'>Delete Picture</a></p>
<input type="button" onclick="getVal(this.value)" class='detailButton1' name='like_name' id='like_id' value='<?php echo $link;?>' title='Like this post'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> Like</input>
```

Javascript:

`<script type="text/javascript">
    function getVal(value)
    {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/photoCheese/like_total/",
        dataType:'json',
        data: {like_id : value},
        error: function(result){
              $('.likeThis').append('<p>goodbye world</p>');
              },
        success: function(result){
          jQuery(".likeThis").html(result);

        }
      });
    }
 </script>`

Controller:

```
public function like_total(){
        $id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
        $upload = $this->input->get('like_id');
        $data = array('like' => 1,
                        'userID'=>$id,
                        'uploadID'=>$_GET['like_id']);

        $result = $this->photoCheese_model->get_like_total($data,$upload);

        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode($result));

        return $result;
    }
```

Model:

```
public function get_like_total($data,$upload){
        $success = $this->db->insert('tbl_like',$data);

        //Query the total likes
        if($success){
            $this->db->select()->from('tbl_like');
            $this->db->where('uploadID',$upload);
            $this->db->where('like !=',2);
            $query = $this->db->get();

            return $query->num_rows();
        }

        return 0;       
    }
```

This code runs perfectly now. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Good answer, but if controller returns array object, how can i update table?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a decent code to me

```
public function like_total(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
    $upload = $this->input->get('like_id');
    $data = array('like' => 1,
                    'userID'=>$id,
                    'uploadID'=>$_GET['like_id']);

    $result = $this->photoCheese_model->get_like_total($data,$upload);


    return json_encode($result);
}
```

Just one try.. change your

> return json_encode($result)

to

> echo json_encode($result)

This example may help you in the future [jquery ajax php example](http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/)

Comment: Please accept it as the answer so that it would be usefull for others if it solved the problem form you. @Jen143Me

Comment: Actually, it does not change anything to the result.

Comment: @Jen143Me is your jquery function being triggered?

Comment: After I click the button, the data is added into the database,,the problem now is `jQuery("#likeThis").html(res.no_likes);` will not change the total likes  displayed in the page

Comment: @jen143Me check the response of your ajax code in your google dev tools in chrome or firebug in mozilla which will give u a clue whats being returned from the php script

Comment: @Jen143Me Are you getting any alert on giving this
 > alert(res.no_likes);

Comment: No alert..that's why also it didn't change the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77278/discussion-between-harigovind-r-and-jen143me).

Comment: @Jen143Me Try viewing the output you obtain when you run the query and its json encoded value

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public function like_total(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
    $upload = $this->input->get('like_id');
    $data = array('like' => 1,
                    'userID'=>$id,
                    'uploadID'=>$_GET['like_id']);

    $no_likes = $this->photoCheese_model->get_like_total($data,$upload);

    $result['no_likes'] = $no_likes;

    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($result)); 
}




public function get_like_total($data,$uplaod){
    $success = $this->db->insert('tbl_like',$data);

    if($success){
        $this->db->select('SUM(`like`) as no_likes');
        $this->db->where('uploadID',$upload);            

        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_like');

        $res = $query->row_array();

        return $res['no_likes'];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You try to set the content type of your output.

Comment: Still not changing the data

Comment: In my view, I don't need to change those?? Maybe there is a problem there

Comment: Using Chrome inspect element feature. Under the Network tab. Check the response of your code. It should return you a json object. Make sure its a valid json object.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function article_search($search){

    $word = explode(' ',$search);   

    $query =  "select c.*,d.name,d.image_link from tbl_product as d inner join tbl_order as c on d.id=c.product_id
    where 1 and ";
    $i=1;
    foreach($word as $wd){
        if($i==1){
            $query.= "( c.customer like '%".$wd."%'";   
        }else{
            $query.=    " or c.customer like '%".$wd."%'";  
        }
        $i++;
    }

    foreach($word as $wd){
        if($i==1){
            $query.= "( c.order_no like '%".$wd."%'";   
        }else{
            $query.=    " or c.order_no like '%".$wd."%'";  
        }
        $i++;
    }
    foreach($word as $wd){
        if($i==1){
            $query.= "( d.name like '%".$wd."%'";   
        }else{
            $query.=    " or d.name like '%".$wd."%'";  
        }
        $i++;
    }
    foreach($word as $wd){
        if($i==1){
            $query.= "( d.commission like '%".$wd."%'"; 
        }else{
            $query.=    " or d.commission like '%".$wd."%'";    
        }
        $i++;
    }
    foreach($word as $wd){
        if($i==1){
            $query.= "( d.base_price like '%".$wd."%'"; 
        }else{
            $query.=    " or d.base_price like '%".$wd."%'";    
        }
        $i++;
    }

        $query.=    " or c.customer like '%".$search."%'";
        $query.=    " or c.order_no like '%".$search."%' ";
        $query.=    " or d.name like '%".$search."%' ";
        $query.=    " or d.commission like '%".$search."%' ";
        $query.=    " or d.base_price like '%".$search."%' )";

    $query = $this->db->query($query);
    //echo $this->db->last_query();die;

    $record = $query->result_array();
    foreach($record as $key=>$value){
        $cat       = $value['product_id'];
        $query_tag = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_product where  id in(".$cat.")");
        $record[$key]['all_pro'] = $query_tag->result_array();            
    }
    return $record;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function like_total(){
$data = array('like' => 1,
                'userID'=>$this->session->userdata('userID'),
                'uploadID'=>$_GET['like_id']);

$no_likes = $this->photoCheese_model->get_like_total($data,$this->input->get('like_id'));

$result['no_likes'] = $no_likes;

 $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($result)); 
}




    public function get_like_total($data,$this->input->get('like_id')){
    $success = $this->db->insert('tbl_like',$data);

    if($success){
    $this->db->select('SUM(`like`) as no_likes');
    $this->db->where('uploadID',$this->input->get('like_id'));            

    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_like');

    $res = $query->row_array();

    return $res['no_likes'];
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation to go with the code?